# MySQL Query Browser alternatives

Tags: mysql, sql

I usually use MySQL Query Browser for my queries, but I always run into issues with the connections timing out and the Query Browser locking up, so I'm looking into alternatives.  The new MySQL Workbench is much too slow and heavyweight, I prefer that the Administrative tools and the Query tools are separate (although it wouldn't be as much of a problem if the application wasn't so slow).  I run on Ubuntu 10.04 x64.  I'd like to avoid Windows/Wine-based solutions as much as possible.  I also have had bad experiences (slow, buggy) with JVM-based MySQL applications, although perhaps other people know more lightweight ones.

I want something lightweight that can show me the schemas, tables, and column tree, and present a decent UI for editing tables.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Some IDEs have plugins to do this, you wouldn't even have to start a separate program.

Comment: Unfortunately most of the old mysql frontends that I used to love have been discontinued by their developer. :(

Comment: I use Eclipse and Netbeans, and both of them are pretty bloated.  I've used SQL plugins with both of them and they're just bogged down by the rest of the IDE.

Comment: i got exactly the same problem now , currently i use phpMyAdmin and sqlyog , however nothing comes eaven close to SequelPro i was using on mac .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it does run on Java and may not be the prettiest thing ever, I pretty much always use Squirrel SQL client. If you haven't tried it, I recommend looking at it.
[Squirrel SQL Client](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 4):

I realize you want to avoid wine, but this might be a good suggestion for you as a free tool.

http://www.heidisql.com/

Comment: Oh man! I can't thank you enough for suggesting this. I was starting to really hate life with Workbench as it hung and crashed often and it was generally very slow. Here are a few things I already LOVE about HeidiSQL:
- It makes it super easy for me to edit my storedprocs. 
- The table filter actually works!
- It seems super fast so far but I've only been using it for an hour
- It displays all the database variables (like Max_connections...) so it's super easy to answer questions

My only gripe is it shows the host name in the 1st tab and my hostname is super long so it takes up space...

Answer (score 0):

+1 for HeidiSQL. On Arch Linux very easy to install. Get tarball from [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/heidisql/);

1. Extract tarball to a directory.
2. In that directory: makepkg -s
3. After building package, install it with: pacman -U packagename

It works perfectly with wine. After trying some sql editors (Oracle SQL Developer, DBVisualizer, MySql Workbench) this was the best choice for me. Lightweigth & fast.